# Datalist unexpected return from eventlistener

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events, addeventlistener, html-datalist

I'm trying to get a return from the datalist selection to print it to the `#body` div and use it to call other function as well, but unfortunately for some reason I get a return of "undefined" printed instead and I can't control the selection to be just from the provided options of the datalist as well.

Any advice to fix both problems would so much appreciated!

```
//Html snippet
<input id="dirSearch" list="dirList" type="text"/>
  <datalist id="dirList"></datalist>

// Array
const db = [
    1,
    2
];

//Functions
function autocomplete () {
  let options = '';
    for(let i = 0; i < db.length; i++)
      options += '<option value="'+db[i]+'">'+db[i]+'</option>';
  document.getElementById('dirList').innerHTML = options;
}
autocomplete();

function searchSelection () {
  let dirSearch = document.getElementById('dirSearch');
  let dirList = document.getElementById('dirList');

  dirSearch.addEventListener ('input', function () {
    document.getElementById('body').innerHTML = "<h1>" +dirList.option+ "</h1>";
  }, false);

}
searchSelection();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getElementById("dirSearch").value instead of dirList.option 
and moreover it is dirList.options -> which returns available options in the datalist.